# RuntimeError: reduce failed to synchronize: device-side assert triggered

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

```
File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py", line 433, in forward     reduce=self.reduce)   
File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1483, in binary_cross_entropy     
return torch._C._nn.binary_cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, reduce)

RuntimeError: reduce failed to synchronize: device-side assert triggered
```

Comment: please consider adding more details to your question.

Answer (score 6):

When using `cuda` you may get this generic error which is not very helpful. Try switching to `cpu` device instead, `device = torch.device("cpu")`, to see the actual error stack trace.

In my case, the issue was caused because binary cross entropy expected the input values to be between 0~1, but I was sending in values between -1 and 1. Applying `sigmoid` to the output resolved that issue.

Comment: may be but was not in my case. thank you for your answer

Comment: I faced the same issue, however even after adding the `sigmoid` layer the issue persisted. Restart your kernel and run all cell (assuming you are using jupyter). This worked for me

Comment: The main point I'm trying to get across here is `device = torch.device("cpu")` to view the actual stack trace causing the error. You should decide on a solution based on your stack trace.